# How can I determine if a HFONT is a raster or a vector font?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'm creating a logical font using `CreateFont()` and `OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS`. Now how can I check if the resulting `HFONT` Windows has allocated for me is a raster or a vector font?

My naive approach would be to just try to get a glyph outline using `GetGlyphOutline()` and if this succeeds, it must be a vector font, else a raster font.

But I'd like to ask if there is a nicer version to examine the `HFONT` handle and tell if it is a raster or a vector font.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`LOGFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfontw) returned by a call to [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) to see if anything would allow you to gather that information?

Comment: @IInspectable: Doesn't look like this can solve the problem. AFAICS the only member in `LOGFONT` that could help here is `lfOutPrecision` but it always seems to be 0, no matter if the `HFONT` is a raster or a vector font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the `HFONT` into an `HDC` via [`SelectObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject), and then pass the `HDC` to [`GetTextMetrics()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextmetrics).  The resulting [`TEXTMETRIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-textmetricw) struct has a `tmPitchAndFamily` field, which has a `TMPF_VECTOR` flag enabled for vector fonts.